# Python Pandas: How can i generate a dataframe out of matching positions between a different dataframe and a numpy vector?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

y_batch is a Dataframe which contains lists with numbers which represent genericarticleid. label_vector is a 3d numpy vector which is filled with genericarticleid, verschleissbehaftette, verschleissteil. I need to generate a dataframe which has the same indices as the y_batch dataframe and has the column number of label_vector.shape[0]. Each row should have zero except in the positions genericarticleids from y_batch and label_vector match.

I managed to get the desire output with this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Example data
y_batch = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]])
label_vector = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
label_ids = label_vector[:, 0].astype(int)

# Initialize the result DataFrame with zeros and matching indices
result_vector = pd.DataFrame(0, index=y_batch.index, columns=range(label_vector.shape[0]))

# Iterate over each row in y_batch
for i, row in y_batch.iterrows():
    # Find the matching indices in label_ids
    indices = np.isin(label_ids, row)
    # Update the result DataFrame at the matching indices
    result_vector.loc[i, indices] = 1

print(result_vector)
```

```
   0  1  2
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  0
```

What I don't get is how to eliminate the for loop in this code. My data is way bigger and I want to save time.

EDIT:
Assume my data has this form.

```
genericarticleid_list = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]

y_batch = pd.DataFrame({'genericarticleid': genericarticleid_list})
label_vector = np.array([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]])
label_ids = label_vector[:, 0].astype(int)
```

Basically I want a dataframe that has a column number of the label_vector rows. In this case there should be 3 column (for genericarticleids 1,4,7). The code should check the matches between each list in y_batch and (1,4,7) in the label_vector and if there are matches like in the first list (1,2) it should have the values 1 0 0. Same logic for the rest of the lists for the rest of the rows in the new dataframe. Does it make sense?

Comment: In your edited example, what is the role of values 2/3/5/6/8/9 of label_vector? Are those just ignored?

Comment: yes. that's why i do this: label_ids = label_vector[:, 0].astype(int). Only the fist values are of importance

Answer (score 0):

The logic is unclear, in particular the way you initialize the output DataFrame's columns with the index of `label_vector`.

However, the logic of the loop could be replaced by:

```
out = y_batch.apply(lambda c: c.isin(label_ids)).astype(int)
```

Or with [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
out = pd.DataFrame(np.isin(y_batch, label_ids).astype(int),
                   index=y_batch.index, columns=y_batch.columns)
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  0
```

Comment: One second, let me try that out in my real code tocheck if it behaves correctly. I'm gonna specify the problem if it's not the desired output. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Updated the question. I hope it makes more sense now